# How to throw a custom exception in polly rate limit exceeds the rate?

Tags: c#, exception, rate-limiting, polly, retry-logic

I have an API that has certain limits defined. Since I have used Polly C# library to limit the calls made to API. Below is the policy I am using.

```
var _rateLimitPolicy = Policy.RateLimitAsync(10,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5);

var _retryPolicy = Policy
           .Handle<RateLimitRejectedException>(e => e.RetryAfter > TimeSpan.Zero)
           .WaitAndRetryAsync(
               retryCount: 3,
               sleepDurationProvider: (i, e, ctx) =>
               {
                   var rle = (RateLimitRejectedException)e;
                   return rle.RetryAfter;
               },
               onRetryAsync: (e, ts, i, ctx) => Task.CompletedTask
           );

_wrappedPolicies = Policy.WrapAsync(_retryPolicy, _rateLimitPolicy);
```

Currently, once the retry limit of 3 is exceeded it throws `RateLimitRejectedException`. I want to throw a custom error if the retry limit is exceeded. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to throw an exception then use System.Exception with an if statement

So:

```
if(retryLimit>3)
{
    throw new System.Exception("Retry Limit exceeded 3.");
}
```

If you don't wish to interrupt the process with a thrown exception, you can use a `try{}catch(Exception e){}` too

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new to this. From where do I get the retry limit?

Comment: If you are not tracking the retry limit somewhere then a `try{}catch(Exception e){}` where you throw your own exception will probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to execute your `_wrappedPolicies`
then you can call [either `ExecuteAsync` or `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-concept-and-architecture#abstract-base-classes-common-to-all-policy-types) methods.

- Former throws the [original exception in case of retry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#how-polly-retry-works)
- Latter captures the result in a [`PolicyResult`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-concept-and-architecture#execution-context) both in failure and success cases

```
PolicyResult policyExecutionResult = await _wrappedPolicies.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(...);
```

On this result object there is a property called [`FinalException`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/f5cc4fe6da9f754dbc770fb64989684a1a7d9417/src/Polly.Shared/PolicyResult.cs#L26). You can examine that and based on the assessment result you can throw a custom exception

```
if (policyExecutionResult.FinalExecption is RateLimitRejectedException)
   throw new CustomException(...);
```